# .htaccess changing directory

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I don't know if title is correctly placed.

I am using .htaccess trying to write readable urls. I am using following configuration. You can get fill .htaccess in the link provided.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

I have created simplest scenario. [Here is a zipped file](http://bunkdeath.com/examples/htaccess/) for the code (Sorry if I am not allowed to put personal site here.)

If you download [the zipped](http://bunkdeath.com/examples/htaccess/) file, and extract and use it in local system and perform following action, you will get what I am trying to say.

assuming

```
localhost/htaccess
```

as the root of my provided code.

if you try 
    localhost/htaccess/first

it executes as expected

if you add one "/" at the end as
    localhost/htaccess/first/

all the folder structure changes. You can see the changes too.

At first case, it assumes

```
localhost/htaccss
```

as root, and loads other files (css, images) from there.

In second case, it assumes

```
localhost/htaccess/first/
```

as root and loads other files after first/. But expected location was htaccess/

I could not explain this in word, so I provided example url with sample case scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit header.php so your stylesheet is relative to the root rather than the path so it can be found regardless of the ending slash:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/htaccess/assets/css/style.css" />
```

Alternatively, you could point the base path to where you need it pointed:

```
<base href="http://localhost/htaccess/" />
```

Comment: Thanks. the base tag part worked. I did not want to use the first part though. For now this did work for me. Hopefully there will be no issue further. Thanks again :)